# TCPDF not showing MICR fonts

Tags: php, fonts, tcpdf

I'm trying to print checks with TCPDF class but the MICR fonts doesn't show up when I want to print the check, any reason why?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

This is How include it

```
// set font
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('micr65.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false);
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 14, '', false);
```

Comment: Do you have the font installed?

Comment: pls try to add absolute path to font. it helps me when i did some thing with tcpdf.

Comment: @StasGrin Can you please show me an example, like how you did that? it will really help me, Thank you

Comment: ok, for example: `$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'path/to_font/on_server/micr65.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
`

Comment: Ok, I tried this too but doesn't work either

Comment: So check you TCPDF config constant `K_PATH_FONTS`. Also check if such font rly exist on server in fonts folder.

Comment: and i dont see your comments without `@name` linked to me :)

Comment: @StasGrin I tried everything you mentioned, nothing seems to work for me, the font exists in the fonts folder, and what you mentioned to check the` K_PATH_FONTS` it looks like everything is okay with it, :(, I dont know what to do next, Appreciate your help.

Comment: now i just dont know what to think about. i have no ideas.

Comment: @StasGrin Thank you anyways, will try to figure out what I can do, and will let you know the results.

Comment: hey i found error in previous code... =\

Comment: here right code (prev. similar wasnt right): `$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont("'".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."path/to_font/on_server/micr65.ttf'", 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);` - seems like i forget to make `path` in quotes. it's final suggestion :)

Comment: and dont forget replace `path/to_font` on a real one path!

Comment: @StasGrin Ok, thats intresting, now I got this error `TCPDF ERROR: Could not find file: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/tcpdf/fonts/micr65.ttf`, but when I remove the path and I put just `../../../tcpdf/fonts/micr65.ttf` then its show up empty, that means that the server not finding the file.

Comment: so here is thea light... just follow it's blessing :)

Comment: pls upload font in tcpdf (or else, try all u can) folder.

Comment: @StasGrin Now, I found out that the font is really installed on the server, but it still comes up blank on pdf, but other fonts is fine, except of those MCIR fonts.

Comment: font cant be `installed`!!! i ask u five times to check if it exists on server.

Comment: @StasGrin Yes it exists on the server, I located it already, but the font is blank when I want to output it on PDF.

Comment: @StasGrin Finaly!!! Got it work, I just need to install another type of this MICR fotns and it works, Thank you very much for your help

Comment: but answer your question with yourself now. dont hold this question like unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the font file, the font wasn't a good font style for PDF, I don't know why, the first font type was invalid, but just to let you know that if you have a problem with one font, don't be afraid its happening, just try another font with the same style.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I believe, the $subset parameter is wrong. It should be true, not false, to embed the whole font subset in your PDF.

```
    $pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', false); // Might be wrong.
    $pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', true); // This should work
```

This might be related:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23812199/997536